# Not able to launch my android application in android AVD emulator using android studio

Tags: android

[image] This is the error that I have mentioned.
  There is no error in program. No problem of AVD RUNNING.
   But I get this type of error

Comment: Did you try to restart the emulator or the whole android studio?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to MENU
2. Go to SETTINGS
3. Go to APPS
4. Look for DOWNLOAD MANAGER under ALL
5. Disable it then enable it

Menu-> Settings-> Apps-> All-> Download Manager (Disable then enable)

That should do the trick.